# Android: Match_parent value not working properly

Tags: android, android-imageview

In the image view with id imageView1 height is set to  match_parent and even then its not occupying the whole height. Some space is left at bottom and top. But if I change its weight to 3 then its working as desired. What could be the reason for it and possible solution to the problem.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/background_img" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="2"

            android:src="@drawable/image031" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            // some code here

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please use dp instead of px.

Comment: done that but no effect as was espected because of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dx"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dx"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        // some code here

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks it worked !! But why is android:scaleType="fitXY" required ??

Comment: if you not using this properties then ImageView cover your given are but image is shown as per witdh and height proportional which by default properties  of ImageView show you have set android:scaleType="fitXY" to shown image given whole area.